# deleting extra fields or submitting the form by ticking check box/es

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a question if I want to add a checkbox so that when I want to delete the added fields by ticking the respective check boxes and pressing the "delete" button or submitting the form by ticking the respective check boxes and pressing the "submit" button.How can I do that?
Below are my codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields= 10;
    var counter = 0;


    $('.addButton').on('click', function(){
        counter++;
        if(counter>=max_fields){
            return;

        }

        var copy = $('.form-copy-wrap').first().clone();

        $("#commentForm fieldset").append(copy);
        });


        $('.delete').on('click', function(){

            $('input:checkbox').closest('.form-copy-wrap').remove(copy);

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
    <div class="majors">
    <h1>Department</h1>
    <form class="hform" id="selectForm" action="/action_page.php">
        <select name="Department">
            <option value="Sociology" selected>Sociology</option>
            <option value="Science">Science</option>
            <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
            <option value="Linguistics">Linguistics</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sbutton">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <button class="delete" type="button" value="delete">Delete</button>
    </form> 
    </section>

    <section class="container">
    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="form-handler.html" autocomplete="">
    <fieldset>


        <div class="form-copy-wrap">
        <input class="tick" type="checkbox"/>

                <p>

                    <label for="aname" >Name</label>
                    <input name="name[]" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
                </p>
                <p>

                    <label for="aemail" >Email</label>
                    <input name="email[]" type="email" required/>
                </p>
                <p>

                    <label for="aage" >Age</label>
                    <input name="age[]" type="number" required/>
                </p>

        </div>

            <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                <div class="addButton">
                    <button type="button" value="add">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/4o7gcpqk/

```js
var max_fields= 10;
var counter = 0;

$('.addButton').on('click', function(){
  counter++;
  if(counter>=max_fields){
    return;
  }

  var copy = $('.form-copy-wrap').first().clone();
 $("#commentForm fieldset").append(copy);
});


$('.delete').on('click', function(){
  $('input:checkbox').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $(this).closest('.form-copy-wrap').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div class="majors">
    <h1>Department</h1>
    <form class="hform" id="selectForm" action="/action_page.php">
      <select name="Department">
        <option value="Sociology" selected>Sociology</option>
        <option value="Science">Science</option>
        <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
        <option value="Linguistics">Linguistics</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <div class="sbutton">
      <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <button class="delete" type="button" value="delete">Delete</button>
  </div> 
</section>

<section class="container">
  <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="form-handler.html" autocomplete="">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-copy-wrap">
        <input class="tick" type="checkbox"/>
        <p> 
          <label for="aname" >Name</label>
          <input name="name[]" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label for="aemail" >Email</label>
          <input name="email[]" type="email" required/>
        </p>
      
        <p>
          <label for="aage" >Age</label>
          <input name="age[]" type="number" required/>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <div class="addButton">
          <button type="button" value="add">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: one question: why isn't all the code written inside $(document).ready(function(){});?

Comment: In jsfiddle it's by default, no need to specify. But in your code you need to provide that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <section class="container">
    <div class="majors">
    <h1>Department</h1>
    <form class="hform" id="selectForm" action="/action_page.php">
        <select name="Department">
            <option value="Sociology" selected>Sociology</option>
            <option value="Science">Science</option>
            <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
            <option value="Linguistics">Linguistics</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sbutton">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <button class="delete" type="button" value="delete">Delete</button>
    </form> 
    </section>

    <section class="container">
    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="form-handler.html" autocomplete="">
    <fieldset>


        <div class="form-copy-wrap">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>

                <p>

                    <label for="aname" >Name</label>
                    <input name="name[]" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
                </p>
                <p>

                    <label for="aemail" >Email</label>
                    <input name="email[]" type="email" required/>
                </p>
                <p>

                    <label for="aage" >Age</label>
                    <input name="age[]" type="number" required/>
                </p>

        </div>

            <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                <div class="addButton">
                    <button type="button" value="add">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>

    </section>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields= 10;
    var counter = 0;


    $('.addButton').on('click', function(){
        counter++;
        if(counter>=max_fields){
            return;

        }

        var copy = $('.form-copy-wrap').first().clone();

        $("#commentForm fieldset").append(copy);
        });


        $('.delete').on('click', function(){

        $('input.checkbox:checked').each(function(index){


            $(this).parents('.form-copy-wrap').remove();

            })


        });

    });

    </script>





</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var max_fields = 10;
var counter = 0;
$('.addButton').on('click', function() {
  counter++;
  if (counter >= max_fields) {
    console.log('You have reached a max limit of fields.');
    return;
  }
  $("#commentForm").append($('.form-copy-wrap').first().parent().clone());
});

$('.delete').on('click', function() {
  $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('fieldset').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div class="majors">
    <h1>Department</h1>
    <form class="hform" id="selectForm" action="/action_page.php">
      <select name="Department">
        <option value="Sociology" selected>Sociology</option>
        <option value="Science">Science</option>
        <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
        <option value="Linguistics">Linguistics</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <div class="sbutton">
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
    <button class="delete" type="button" value="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
  <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="form-handler.html" autocomplete="">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-copy-wrap">
        <input class="tick" type="checkbox" />
        <p>
          <label for="aname">Name</label>
          <input name="name[]" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label for="aemail">Email</label>
          <input name="email[]" type="email" required/>
        </p>

        <p>
          <label for="aage">Age</label>
          <input name="age[]" type="number" required/>
        </p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div class="addButton">
    <button type="button" value="add">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```